# Merging two different spreadsheets database data

Tags: sql, database, excel

newbie here working on something bit complicated..not sure how to start and whats the best way..looking for some advice and tips

So, we have 2 system running using MS Dynamics POS 2009 and have extract of all data (inventory/stock) in spreadsheets. Both dbo have pretty much the same items but because they have been run separately all naming and Part Numbers are in different format.

I need to create one database (one excel file) from both. Where partial match on Part Number will be identified and "merged" (keeping Part Number and Description from sheet1 and updating Stock (sheet1 stock + stock from sheet2)

Problem is that Part Numbers are written in completely different styles (by different people) and can by match only by some partial match (i guess last 3-6 characters in Part numbers)

I am not excel expert so any advice and tips would be appreciated. 
Also have thoughts of loading those excel sheets into 2 separate SQL databases and doing it from SSMS as not sure if excel can cope with this

Thanks

Comment: If excel is getting its data from databases, take it out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the source data, but based on the available information here are some possible steps:

-Create a new Database in SSMS
-Load the data from your excel extracts in with the import data tool (Right on your newly-created database, tasks, Import data). This
will pull up a wizard that will transform your Excel spreadsheet to a table in SQL server. Do this for all spreadsheets
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/The-SQL-Server-Import-and-Export-Wizard-how-to-guide

-You may be able to do some matching based on the start/end of characters and use a MERGE statement to get unique data. The merge statement
allows you to set a match criteria, and then take certain actions depending on a positive or negative match. For example, if your different POS
systems have two different spreadsheets of products where there is some overlap, but also some products that are unique to each system, you could start with a source table from the first system and only insert products into it that are unique to the other system, if there is a match do nothing. Something like

MERGE ProductA A
USING ProductB B
ON RIGHT(A.ProductID, 5) = RIGHT(B.ProductID,5)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (ProductID, Descrption)
VALUES (b.ProductID, b.Description)

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/